# Routine to perform actions in Tasks, showing a loading screen, without freezing the main form

Tags: multithreading, exception, delphi, task, loading

I'm looking to build a routine that is responsible for executing any action via procedure (Tproc) using Tasks, while displaying a loading screen, without freezing the system's main form. An extra detail is that it is also capable of capturing a possible exception that the action may have generated.

I built the code below, which works well, but sometimes something goes wrong and the loading screen ends up not closing, remaining always present on the screen.

Any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks.

```
type
  TLoadingClass= class
  strict private
    class var FForm: TForm;

  public
    class procedure ActionAndWait(Action: Tproc);
  end;

class procedure TLoadingClass.ActionAndWait(Action: Tproc);
var
  aTask: ITask;
  vException: Pointer;
begin
  vException := nil;

  FForm := TLoadingForm.Create(nil);
  try
    aTask := TTask.Run(procedure
      begin
        try
          try
            Action; {Run Action}
          except on E: Exception do
            vException := @E {Capture Exception}
          end
        finally
          while not FForm.Showing do {Wait for the form to be created, if the action is very quick.}
            Sleep(1);
          TLoadingForm(FForm).Hide;
          TLoadingForm(FForm).Close;
        end;
      end);
    TLoadingForm(FForm).ShowModal; {Show the loading form}
  finally
    TTask.WaitForAll(aTask);
    FreeAndNil(FForm);
    if Assigned(vException) then
      raise Exception(@vException);
  end;
end;
```

Call example

```
  TLoadingClass.ActionAndWait(
  procedure
  begin
    try
      Sleep(5000);
      raise Exception.Create('Test');
    except on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end);
```

Comment: You cannot do UI work inside a thread. You must wrap your `TLoadingForm(` calls inside `TThread.Synchronize(` and let the main UI thread schedule the form updates for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues.

First, you are accessing the UI (form) from the background thread which you should never do. Such code always needs to be synchronized with the main thread.

Next, you are not handling task exceptions properly. Exception objects are automatically handled by compiler and you cannot just grab a pointer to the exception object and use it later on. The whole `try...except` within task method is useless. If there is unhandled exception within the task, `Wait` or `WaitForAll` will raise `EAggregatedException` and you can catch that exception and handle its inner exception(s) there. If there are multiple tasks that raised exceptions, there will be multiple inner exceptions.

Next, you are already catching the exception inside anonymous method passed to `ActionAndWait` so such captured exception will not be propagated as `EAgreggatedException`. `ShowMessage` within `ActionAndWait` will run in the context of the background thread and if you want to use and UI from there it also needs to be synchronized with the main thread.

You have `FForm` declared as field in `TLoadingClass`. It would be better that you remove that field and use local variable like you are using for the task. Also there is no need to typecast `FForm` as `TLoadingForm` when you are calling `Hide` and `Close`. Besides that, calling `Close` is sufficient as it will also hide the form.

Cleaned and corrected code would look like:

```
class procedure TLoadingClass.ActionAndWait(Action: Tproc);
var
  LTask: ITask;
  LForm: TLoadingForm;
begin
  try
    LTask := TTask.Create(procedure
      begin
        try
          Action;
        finally
          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              LForm.Close;
            end);
        end;
      end);
    LForm := TLoadingForm.Create(nil);
    try
      try
        LTask.Start;
        LForm.ShowModal;
      finally
        TTask.WaitForAll(LTask);
      end;
    finally
      LForm.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: EAggregateException do
      for var i := 0 to E.Count - 1 do
        ShowMessage(E.InnerExceptions[i].Message);
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

And the call example:

```
  TLoadingClass.ActionAndWait(
  procedure
  begin
    Sleep(5000);
    raise Exception.Create('Test');
  end);
```

Comment: "*you cannot just grab a pointer to the exception object and use it later on*" - you can if you use `System.AcquireExceptionObject()` to release the RTL's hold on the exception object.  Then you can do whatever you want with it, just make sure you `Free` it when you are done using it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True. But you cannot grab it like the OP did. And it is simpler to use `EAggregateException` in this particular scenario.

Comment: Thank you Friend, this is beautiful. It worked very well.
I made a small change by changing the position of finally, to:

LForm.Free;
TTask.WaitForAll(LTask);

Because in case of exception "Free" was not happening.
Greetings from Brazil

Comment: Good catch. It could also be solved with double try...finally blocks.